# Value of Kubernetes secret in environment variable seems incorrect

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm deploying a test application onto kubernetes on my local computer (minikube) and trying to pass database connection details into a deployment via environment variables.

I'm passing in these details using two methods - a `ConfigMap` and a `Secret`. The username (`DB_USERNAME`) and connection url (`DB_URL`) are passed via a `ConfigMap`, while the DB password is passed in as a secret (`DB_PASSWORD`).

My issue is that while the values passed via `ConfigMap` are fine, the `DB_PASSWORD` from the secret appears jumbled - like there's some encoding issue (see image below).

[image: DB_PASSWORD not showing up properly]

My deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: gweb-cm
        - secretRef:
            name: password
```

My `ConfigMap` and `Secret` yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql/test?serverTimezone=UTC
  DB_USERNAME: webuser
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod
  SPRING_DDL_AUTO: create
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gweb-cm
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: password
type: Generic
data:
  DB_PASSWORD: test
```

Not sure if I'm missing something in my Secret definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret value should be base64 encoded. Instead of `test`, use the output of

```bash
echo -n 'test' | base64
```

P.S. the Secret's type should be `Opaque`, not `Generic`

Comment: Ahh.. I see. That worked. Thanks a lot. Also, I was previously using `Opaque` and decided to try `Generic` because I thought Opaque might be the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Kubernetes Secret values either using `data` key or `stringData` key.
When you use `data` key, you have to encode values in base64. When you use `stringData` key, Kubernetes encodes values to base64 for you.
`stringData` is more convenient for a human but you cannot pass binary data this way. In those cases you must use `data` and encode to base64.
You can also combine both approaches.

Following two manifests are equivalent.
First one uses `data` key:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: password
type: Opaque
data:
  DB_PASSWORD: dGVzdA== # output from: `echo -n test | base64`
```

and second manifest uses `stringData` key:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: password
type: Opaque
stringData:
  DB_PASSWORD: test
```

See documenation [Secret | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/secret-v1/#Secret).